# Getting a loaded store in extjs4

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I am getting null while I try to obtain a loaded store from the controller. The load is a successful one too. I verified that.

I have the store as follows.

```
Ext.define('GridApp.store.schemedatastore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'GridApp.model.schemedatamodel',
    autoLoad: true,
    alias: 'store.schemedata',
    storeId: 'schemedatastoreid',
    constructor:function(){
        console.log('Calling parent');
        this.callParent(arguments);
        },
    listeners: {
        load:function(store,records,isSuccessful){
            if(isSuccessful){
                console.log('Load successful');
            }
            console.log(records[0].get('name'));
            console.log('scheme Data store loaded too.');
        },
    }
});
```

In my controller I added like,

```
stores: ['schemesstore',
             'schemedatastore'],
```

I tried accessing in these both ways in the controller,

`Ext.getStore('schemedatastoreid');` which returns null and
`this.getschemedatastoreStore();` which says it is an undefined function in controller.

Am I missing something over here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
this.getSchemedatastoreStore()

// the non-alias version of getStore    
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('schemedatastoreid') 

// in case MVC behavior overrides your storeId config
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('schemedatastore')
```

MVC pattern will give your store the store class name as a store ID automatically if you don't define your own.

So if you delete your `storeId: 'schemedatastoreid'` config then you will automatically get a storeId of `schemedatastore`. I don't normally give MVC stores a seperate `storeId` config so I don't know if it causes a conflict somewhere. I also don't normally give my stores an alias either, that might be causing the `getStore` function some difficulties too.

Comment: yeah.. Loaded through the controller and having a storeid does conflict. Even the documentation says, Storeid assigned automatically for the controller loaded stores. Stupid me.. Thanks @Geronimo.. Now it works like charm..

Comment: In MVC, I couldn't explicitly assign the "storeId" config.  So #2 did not work in ExtJS 4.2 MVC.  I had to use #3 based on the store class name.